# Given non-invertible square $A$, find a square matrix $B$ so that $BA$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have one not invertible $n\times n$-matrix $A$ and want to know how can I find suitable square matrix $B$ that product of $BA$ is invertible.

Comment: Would this be possible given that $(BA)^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1}$ and you have already stated that A is singular?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such matrix. If $A$ is not invertible, then there's a nonzero vector $v$ with $Av = 0$. But if you could find $B$, you'd have

$$
0 = B(0) = B(Av)= (BA) v
$$
and this would mean that
$$
0 = (BA)^{-1} 0 = (BA)^{-1} B(0) = (BA)^{-1} B(Av)= (BA)^{-1} (BA) v = Iv = v
$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. Remember two things: a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero, and that for two $n\times n$ matrices $B,A$ you have $\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A).$ So if $A$ is not invertible, then for all $n\times n$ matrices $B$ you have $$\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)=\det(B)\cdot 0 =0.$$ Hence $BA$ can never be invertible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such matrix. BA has still not full rank. Let v be vector from A kernel. So $Av=0$. Then $BAv=0$.